# 2 Squares in a circle

Tags: geometry

In a circle there are two squares with side length $a$ and $b$ with $a\leq b$.
Of each of the circles 2 vertices lie on the circle the other 2 lie on THE SAME secant.
What is the shortest distance '$x$' between the secant and the center of the circle in respect to $a$ and $b$ ?

Not sure how to start :/. The diagonals intersect at the midpoint of the secant, but that's pretty much all :/

Comment: I assume you mean "of each of the squares"? Do you mean that each square has two vertices on the circle, and the other two on a line with the center of the circle?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand your question, your configuration has to look somewhat like this:

[image: Generic situation]

If that is the case, then you can simply start off with two squares, which have one edge line in common and which are aligned on that edge line in such a way that the centers of the respective edges agree. Make that center the origin of your coordinate system, and make the edge line vertical. Then you should be able to come up with coordinates for all the corners, expressed in terms of $a$ and $b$. You can use these corners to compute the center of the circumcircle, and from that read the distance you were asking about.

[image: Labeled picture]

\begin{align*}
O &= (0, 0) \\
A &= \left(-a, -\tfrac 12a\right) \\
B &= \left(b, \tfrac 12b\right) \\
D &= \frac{A+B}2 = \left(\frac{b-a}{2}, \frac{b-a}{4}\right) \\
\ell_{AB} &= \left\{(x,y)\;\middle\vert\;x-2y=0\right\} \\
\ell_{CD} &= \left\{(x,y)\;\middle\vert\;2x+y=2x_D+y_D=\tfrac54(b-a)\right\} \\
y_C &= 0 \\
2x_C &= \tfrac54(b-a) \\
x_C &= \tfrac58(b-a) \\
d(C,O) &= \tfrac58\cdot\lvert b-a\rvert
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You get the same result by looking at the distance from the centre to points on the circle.
$r^2=(a-x)^2+(a/2)^2=(b+x)^2+(b/2)^2$, and solve for $x$.